# How to assign an empty value to a column of complex type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a dataframe into a dataset corresponding to the model `EmailToSend`.

My models object:

```
object Models {
    case class EmailToSend(
        a1: String,
        promoCodeTemplate: Option[PromoCodeTemplate]
    )

    case class PromoCodeTemplate(
        b1: String
    )
}
```

My code:

```
val myDataset: Dataset[Models.EmailToSend] = myDf.as[Models.EmailToSend]
```

`myDf` contains all columns required by EmailToSend, except promoCodeTemplate. As a consequence, this code fails at runtime:

```
cannot resolve '`promoCodeTemplate`' given input columns: [a1];
```

`promoCodeTemplate` is missing from that dataframe, which is what I expect. It will be filled later, but for now it has to be empty: there is no promo code template, this is normal.

The problem is that I cannot make this work without filling it with a promo code template. I tried to add an empty value with a `withColumn` but no value I tried worked.

```
val myDataset: Dataset[Models.EmailToSend] = myDf
    // this is one of the many values I tried
    .withColumn("promoCodeTemplate", lit(null.asInstanceOf[Models.PromoCodeTemplate]).cast(Models.PromoCodeTemplate))
    .as[Models.EmailToSend]
```

How do I assign an empty value to the column `promoCodeTemplate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an empty struct field to match spark type with case class `PromoCodeTemplate`.

```
val myDataset = myDF.withColumn("promoCodeTemplate", struct(lit("").as("b1"))).as[EmailToSend]
```

Or, you can use below line also,

```
myDF.withColumn("promoCodeTemplate", typedLit(PromoCodeTemplate(""))).as[EmailToSend]
```

To simply add null value,

```
myDF.withColumn("promoCodeTemplate", typedLit(null.asInstanceOf[PromoCodeTemplate])).as[EmailToSend]
```

Comment: What if promoCodeTemplate contained multiple props, eg: b1: String and b2: Option[Boolean]?

Comment: Updated the answer please check--> You can try with  `myDF.withColumn("promoCodeTemplate", typedLit(PromoCodeTemplate("", None))).as[EmailToSend]`

Comment: ok thanks I understand better. However this is not exactly what I wish to do. I do not wish promoCodeTemplate to contain a PromoCodeTemplate with empty values. I wish promoCodeTemplate to contain an empty value. Later in the code I need to access it and check whether it is `None` or not.

Comment: This is still the same thing: assigning a instance of PromoCodeTemplate, instead of assigning an emtpy value

Comment: Try this - `myDF.withColumn("promoCodeTemplate", typedLit(null.asInstanceOf[PromoCodeTemplate])).as[EmailToSend]`

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you for your help! :)